# IAsyncResult's WaitHandle and blocking?

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, asynchronous, iasyncresult

Let's say I have this code :

```
  public class MyAsyncHandler : IHttpAsyncHandler
    {
      public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
      {
        MyAsynchOperation asynch = new MyAsynchOperation(cb, context, extraData);
        asynch.StartAsyncWork();
        return asynch;
      }
     //...
```

Now  , if `MyAsynchOperation` is an IO operation  , so it probably have internal methods (APM) of `BeginFOO/EndFOO` **which are not tying a thread.**

When the operation is finished , a new/same thread from the thread pool (via completion ports) is dealing with the response.

All ok.

**But** one of the things which makes me wonder is that `IAsyncResult` has this property :

`System.Threading.WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle { get; }`

I'm familiar with `WaitHadnle` that it has a methods to *block* the current thread.
A thread *waits, or blocks*, at the turnstile by calling `WaitOne` (for example).

And so here is my questions :

**Question #1**

- Assuming `MyAsynchOperation` *is* using the APM for IO , *How*(*for what*) does `waitHAndle` is being used if there is **no** blocking/tying a thread ?

**Question #2**

- Assuming `MyAsynchOperation` *is NOT* using the APM and it's just my implementation which internally calls `new Thread().start(do some calculation)` which I later  later call `AsyncCallback's` `Callback` ---- does `waithandle` here blocks a thread ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#1:

The entire point of `WaitOne` here is to allow people to write synchronous code that waits for completion; if you don't need to use methods like `WaitOne`, `WaitAny` etc - then *don't use them*; that's fine.

#2:

In *both* cases, whether it uses a dedicated thread, or whether it completes via some other callback, yes it blocks a thread: it blocks the thread that has requested to be blocked by calling `WaitOne`. If you don't want that: don't call `WaitOne`.

---

Aside: since you specify 4.0, you might find it more intuitive to return a `Task<T>` instead, using `TaskCompletionSource<T>`. Edit: I realize now that this isn't an option due to satisfying the `IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest` method.

Comment: Thanks for reply Marc, but still regarding #1 , I know whta's the purpose of waithandle , But I also know that APM is not tying/blocking a thread (io operation) . so how come this happens ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir how come what happens? Please be specific.

Comment: how come waitHandle is used in IAsyncResult for IO operations without blocking where , waithandle DOES blocks ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir `WaitHandle` only blocks if it is requested to do so; you can use `IAsyncResult` without ever touching `WaitHandle`. It is there to *allow* certain patterns of use. It isn't used for every scenario.

Comment: @RoyiNamir no, the **most common** pattern is that the caller passes in a callback (`cb`) that is invoked when the work is complete. The caller then calls `End*` passing in the `IAsyncResult` token, and gets the reply. I think I've used `WaitHandle` once, maybe twice.

Comment: Marc, so in your last comment , the caller thread was not blocking  ...right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir correct; the original thread called `Begin*` then went away to do something else. The callback most likely won't even happen on the same thread. Unless of course the completion is actually synchronous (there's a flag for that - `CompletedSynchronously`)

Comment: Marc , but what if the original thread calls myBeginxxx which is not (!) doing  IO , but just sleep for a sec , would the calling (!) thread would be blocked ? .....(im trying to figure if it's also wont block on a non-IO operation)...

Comment: @RoyiNamir that depends when the "just sleep for a sec" happens. If that happens inside the `Begin*`, then yes of course it will be blocked. If it happens *separately*, then of course it won't be blocked.

Comment: Mybeginxxx is calling sleep . But i asked about the calling thread which runs mybeginxxx , would it be blocked ?

Comment: @Royi if you are still on the calling thread: then yes. If you aren't: then no. If the sleep happens before the caller exits the Begin* method, then yes it will be blocked for the duration of the sleep. What else could possibly happen? (Edit: at least without "await" rewriting the method)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50707/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-marc-gravell)

Comment: Marc , regarding your edit, i've just noticed that Task implements  IasyncResult , so basically i could return cast to IasyncResult .... No ?

Comment: @Royi interesting. I've never tried it. Let me know how that works out.